# FileNotFoundError when I read a file

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas

HELP, does someone understand why it is giving me this error?

```py
import tensorflow
import keras
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import sklearn
from sklearn import linear_model
from sklearn.utils import shuffle


data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")

data = data[["G1","G2","G3","studytime","failures","absences"]]

print(data.head())
```

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/Users/tanyapaul/PycharmProjects/pythonProject5/main.py", line 12, in <module>
    data = pd.read_csv("student-mat.csv", sep=";")
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 688, in read_csv
    return _read(filepath_or_buffer, kwds)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 454, in _read
    parser = TextFileReader(fp_or_buf, **kwds)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 948, in __init__
    self._make_engine(self.engine)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 1180, in _make_engine
    self._engine = CParserWrapper(self.f, **self.options)
  File "/opt/anaconda3/envs/tensor/lib/python3.6/site-packages/pandas/io/parsers.py", line 2010, in __init__
    self._reader = parsers.TextReader(src, **kwds)
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 382, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader.__cinit__
  File "pandas/_libs/parsers.pyx", line 674, in pandas._libs.parsers.TextReader._setup_parser_source
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'student-mat.csv'
```

Thank you for your help :)

Comment: What do you understand from that error message?

Comment: Yeah looks like the file you've specified either doesn't exist or at least it's in a different folder to the .py file you're running